# in MVVM does a property in a model need a property changed event if the UI doesn't need to update?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing an automation application in WPF that has a page that asks the user to enter in username, password, servername, database username, and database password. I am trying to write the application using MVVM and have been following both videos and online resources, however most of the sources simply say that if you use data binding the model should have property changed events for the properties and they leave it at that. My issue is, I see a property changed event as a way to update the UI in the application, but I don't need to update the UI when a username is entered or a password is entered. I only need the username that is entered to be stored in the property to be used at a later time. So even though there is no need to update the UI I am wondering whether or not a property changed event needs to be raised.

```
public class Model
{
    private string username;
    private string serverName;
    private string password;

    //this is where my question is
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }
        set
        {
            if(username != value)
            {
                username = value;

                //if the username doesn't need to be updated in the UI
                //does the property changed event need to be raised or 
                //used?
                RaisePropertyChanged(Username);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. That should be a viewmodel rather than a model and all viewmodels should implement inotifypropertychanged ( unless they're dependency objects but that's rarely a good plan). Only properties that need to notify change need do so.

Comment: It 's very common to copy values from a model instance to a vm and bind view to the vm. Then back vm to model in order to update.

Comment: Is there a reason that this should be a viewmodel rather than a model? If I understand the model correctly, it is where the viewmodel should get its data, so the viewmodel, I thought should have an instance of this model for access to that data

Comment: @helplessprogrammer If it's never going to need to raise any change notifications, it shouldn't raise any. That's not all there is to the model/viewmodel distinction: I'd go pretty close to saying that anything with commands is a ViewModel, for example. But if it's just a bare class with properties and no notifications and maybe a constructor or two, that sure sounds like a model.

Comment: Also going from programming regular applications, should a model contain the methods necessary on that type of data, so in this case if I need to call the server and load data from the server, should I create a LoadData() method in the model or the viewmodel?

Comment: [I would put](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515420/424129) as much of the data access detail as possible in a class specifically for that purpose, which would be part of "the model" broadly speaking. So the "model" includes model classes which represent entities, and also classes for retrieving those entity classes from the data store. In the viewmodel realm, a UserListViewModel would go to the data access claass(es) for a list of Users, and create a UserViewModel for each User model object.

Comment: ...that is, assuming there's a need for a UserViewModel. I couldn't think of a more appropriate example off the top of my head. Maybe an InsurancePolicyViewModel goes to the data layer to retrieve models for its Provisions and Claims and Payments and its Customer, and creates corresponding viewmodels for all those entities.

Comment: "The model" starts to sound a lot like Entity Framework, and not by chance.

Comment: As a layer, the model is whatever returns data. The object your data arrives in comes from that and it's content is consumed by a viewmodel. The purpose of a viewmodel is as a sort of adapter between a dumb view and the data source (model). The reason you shouldn't pollute that class you get your data in is nothing to do with mvvm really. It's more solid or just sound design. A class should have a narrow set of responsibilities. In solid that's described as one reason for change. Taken literally you could end up with some convoluted viewmodels so maybe don't take that too literal.

Comment: Someone coming from mvc might be thinking model is equivalent to @model. It's not. One of those model is often not just an entity framework class or dto. They're often a composed class with data from more than one source and more like the data in a viewmodel. But a wpf viewmodel will also have commands (etc) which correspond to parts of a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according the Microsoft Documentation, it is just fo change notifications, so, if you dont need it, it is unnecessary. But I would recommend you to dont use de Property Change directly on your model, replicate your property to your ViewModel, and use there. Keep your model the most clean that you can. And I think that if you dont need the property change, your binding can be just One Way, it is better for performance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification